# How to run python script from java ee web application in aws elastic beanstalk?

Tags: python-2.7, jakarta-ee, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I am working on a java ee application that makes some api calls and passes the result of those api calls to a [python](/questions/tagged/python) script in the form of a json file. Locally, my application works just fine but when i try to test it on AWS Elastic Beanstalk, my project doesn't run the python script at all.

While deploying my web application on [aws-eb](/questions/tagged/aws-eb) i have selected [tomcat](/questions/tagged/tomcat) as my platform and uploaded my .war file.

Since my project is a simple one, i have left rest of the configurations as they were.

In my code, I and creating a runtime process which calls a bash script which in turn runs the python script.
My bash script is as:
`#!/bin/bash
DIR="$( cd "$( dirname "${BASH_SOURCE[0]}" )" && pwd )"
python $DIR/json_to_matches.py $DIR/output.json`

I have included a `print("Running python script")` statement in the beginning of my python script for debugging purpose.

The screenshot of my local output is:
[image]

But when i deploy my app and test it, my logs show that python script wasn't hit at all.

[image]

I have checked my webroot directories on eb cli and my output.json file is being created by the project, so I don't think it's the issues of output.json file not being found or read/write permissions.

However, I am new to AWS-EB and i may be doing something wrong while deploying my app. I am not sure. Does anyone have any idea how i can run python scripts from my Java EE web application in aws-eb environment?

Answer (score 1):

try running using the Runtime class.

```
 Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("python example.py");
```

if python is not in your PATH variable use the address of python install directory as

```
 Runtime.getRuntime().exec("/usr/local/bin/python example.py")
```

You can read the output of the command as below:

```
        BufferedReader stdInput = new BufferedReader(new 
             InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
```

Comment: I am already using Runtime process to execute the python script. There is no path dependency either. Not in my local host, neither in aws eb when i checked via eb cli. As I mentioned above, in my local host the project runs fine, i am having issues while trying to execute it on aws eb.

Comment: Could you please check the execute permission on your shell script and python script. Both should be executable.

Comment: Both shell script and python script have execute permission for users. I have already checked that.

Comment: try running this ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("sudo","sh", "/home/ec2-user/testscript.sh"); Process p = pb.start(); int errCode =p.waitFor(); your code will run for sure check the error code if it fails( 0 for success , non zero otherwise)